# How do I group data by fiscal year in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, period

I have the following dataframe containing financial data for a company which has its fiscal year from 1 March to the last day of February. The real dataframe covers multiple fiscal years.

| date | fcf | debt_service | cash_or_overdraft | cash_generated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017Q1 | 38 | 0 | -36.0 | 14.5 |
| 2017Q2 | -24 | 0 | -101.4 | -65.3 |
| 2017Q3 | 21 | 0 | -92.8 | 8.5 |
| 2017Q4 | 89 | -145 | -115.0 | 15.3 |
| 2018Q1 | 17 | -150 | -140.4 | -25.8 |
| 2018Q2 | 36 | -130 | -59.5 | 80.8 |
| 2018Q3 | 50 | -162 | -179.9 | -120.4 |
| 2018Q4 | 29 | -147 | -142.0 | -6.3 |

I want to aggregate the data for each fiscal year. I tried the following method. However, it seems to aggregate the data based on *calendar* year, not *fiscal* year. This throws out my totals, because the totals don't reconcile with the actual fiscal year.

```
debt_service = df2.groupby(df2['index'].dt.year)['debt_service'].agg(['sum', 'mean', 'max'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try extracting the year of the period object.

```py
data = [ {"period" : pd.Period('2018Q1', freq='Q-FEB'), "value" : 1000},
        {"period" : pd.Period('2018Q2', freq='Q-FEB'), "value" : 1000},
        {"period" : pd.Period('2018Q3', freq='Q-FEB'), "value" : 1000},
        {"period" : pd.Period('2018Q4', freq='Q-FEB'), "value" : 1000},
        {"period" : pd.Period('2019Q1', freq='Q-FEB'), "value" : 2000},
        {"period" : pd.Period('2019Q2', freq='Q-FEB'), "value" : 2000},
        {"period" : pd.Period('2019Q3', freq='Q-FEB'), "value" : 2000},
        {"period" : pd.Period('2019Q4', freq='Q-FEB'), "value" : 2000}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

With list comprehension

```py
df["fiscal_year"] = [x.qyear for x in df["period"].values]
```

Or with apply

```py
def get_fiscal_year(row):
  row["fiscal_year"] = row["period"].qyear
  return row

df["fiscal_year"] = None
df = df.apply(get_fiscal_year, axis=1)
```

And then, make the groupby:

```py
df.groupby('fiscal_year')['debt_service'].agg(['sum','mean','max'])
```